# Honda CBR 150R won't start after leaving idle for a day?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, starting

My Honda CBR 150R won't start after I leave it idle for a day.

I have to apply the self start for like 45-50 seconds to make the engine start. I have to do this every morning I try to start the engine.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It sounds like you're saying the bike will turn over (crank), but won't start during the 45-50 seconds? If so, this **DEFINITELY** is not a battery/alternator issue.

Comment: I m using past 5years but nothing problem..the problem is skitting...

Answer (score 1):

It is natural for an engine which sits idle for a long time to have some starting trouble .What you can do is:

1. Apply choke to start it if the engine is cold (first start in the morning)
2. Check for the spark plug if it is alright, i.e the gap between the electrodes.
3. Ideally a spark plug lasts for around 10 to 15k kms before it starts giving trouble ensure that you dont have a very old one.

Comment: Engine was only idle for 24 hrs.. Not for a very long time. And CBR 150R dont have choke.. What can be other possible problem?

Comment: You can try replacing spark plug if you have not from past 10 to 15 k kms.

Comment: Sparks sound good to test.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the battery or the alternator is on its way out. How often is servicing done at Honda? 
I would recommend you get the battery tested first. 
Could be something as simple as a contact eating up battery which should be removed.

Comment: Self-start motor is working fine because even after applying self-start for 45-50 seconds, it continues to work..which can be an indicator that battery is ok. Is it possible that either fuel pump is not working fine or Spark plug is bad??

Comment: No offense but if you get the battery and alternator tested at Honda it wouldn't cost much. Now to your question, a bad spark plug or a falling fuel pump would act up even while you're ridding the bike. But a weak battery or a failing Alternator don't necessarily act up while riding, but show signs by giving trouble while starting. Your bike just has one spark plug, if there was any problem it would hesitate a bit on hills, cause RPM bouncing while idling, may even turn off at low RPM revs.

Comment: You'd like us to help, yet you don't want us to point anything. Everyone here will have different opinions. It's all based on the probability of what you said as your signs of not starting. If we had to fully diagnose it ourselves we'll come to the same conclusion, but that's not the case here. A weak piston with a shaved head can let gasoline sweep in to the oil chamber, this would account for the rough start, now we don't know that, the only way to check that would be with an oil level test, if it increases gradually expect a piston ring overhaul.

Comment: In many cases it could also be a high fuel dumping syndrome, maybe more than required fuel is dumped in the cylinder bore, and the spark plug is not able to burn it up hence the hesitation until 50 seconds.

Comment: I don't get paid for this, yet some people remove rating from my posts. God bless cheapness.

Comment: I hope you don't use the accelerator too much while starting. This could pump in more gasoline than required. New engines don't not require gas to be pumped.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback.. I appreciate your valuable time to dig into this question.. I did my last servicing 2 months ago and I guess the guy at the service centre didn't do it properly. However as per your suggestion I'll definitely get the battery tested and keep you posted for further queries...

Comment: Any update, Vineet?

Comment: I'm going to be in Koramangla upcoming Saturday. Let me know if you need a second opinion on your Honda.